# Ember.js + socket.io

Tags: ember.js, socket.io

I really could use some pointers in the right direction.
I'm new to Ember.js, but I'm eager to use it for my game.

Background: I'm creating a multiplayer html5 (mostly textbased) game in Node.JS + Socket.io.

What I want to achieve:

- Application wide: load and keep the player data updated
- On the "homepage" (index view): load and keep a list of active games

On the backend I'm emitting two things:

- the player data: socket.emit('player data', data);
- a list with active games: socket.emit('available games', data);

Displaying the player data was easy. My template has a {{userName}} and {{balance}} placeholder.

I'm using the following code to display the actual userName and balance:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller) {
        var socket;

        socket = io.connect();

        controller.set('socket', socket);
    }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    userName: null,
    balance: null,
    playerDataChanged: function () {
        var socket, self;

        socket = this.get('socket');
        self = this;

        socket.on('player data', function (player) {
            console.log(player);
            self.set('userName', player.username);
            self.set('balance', satoshiToMBTC(player.balance));
        });
    }.observes('socket')
});
```

This works fine. I'm now trying to the same for the list with actual games. But I honestly have no clue how I would do this.
If I create a games model it keeps trying to do: GET  127.0.0.1:5555/games 404 (Not Found). Of course this won't work since I don't have a REST api, but I'm emitting live data.

So to recap:

My server is emitting an array with game objects containing information on those games. I want to loop over those games and display them to the user.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I looked at the first 5 pages on Google for "ember.js + socket.io" but I just can't seem to get it work.

Comment: The short short version of what I need to say is: this paradigm won't really work. Ember.js displays certain data at certain times, and there's no guarantee that it will be displaying your data when your socket.io event is happening. You need to make the data available to Ember.js _when it requests the data_. I think that if you start with an Ember-Data model and the Ember-Data fixture adapter (without your socket.io server), the way Ember.js works will become a bit more clear to you.

Comment: Have you tried EmberSockets? (https://github.com/Wildhoney/EmberSockets)  It allows you to bind a controller function to a socket.io channel.  Anytime an event is received on a specific channel a function in your controller is called and is passed the socket.io data.  You could then take that data and add it to your ArrayController model to display all the games.

Answer (score 4):

There's a good example of sockets and ember.js in [this EmberConf 2015 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfGORL8ebn8), it uses a new approach of using services

Answer (score 2):

There is a good enough package: [ember-websockets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-websockets#socketio-support)

Step by step:

**1. Install:**

```
ember install ember-websockets
```

**2. init socket-io:**

```
ember g socket-io
```

**3. write route/component/controller:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    socketio: Ember.inject.service('socket-io'),

    myThisActivationHandler() {
        const socket = this.get('socketio').socketFor('http://localhost:7000/');
        socket.on('connect', this.onConnect, this);
        socket.on('message', this.onMessage, this);
    },

    onConnect(data) {
        const socket = this.get('socketio').socketFor('http://localhost:7000/');
        socket.send('Hello World');
    },

    onMessage(data) {
        // This is executed within the ember run loop
        this.set('messageTextOrSomethingElse', data);
    },

    myThisDestroyHandler() {
        const socket = this.get('socketio').socketFor('http://localhost:7000/');
        socket.off('connect', this.onConnect);
        socket.off('message', this.onMessage);
    }
})
```